# How to combine main .apk file and .obb file

Tags: android, game-engine

According to Google Play's store rules, you cannot upload an apk file larger than 50 MB, so I have to create a `.obb` file. Is there a way to combine the `.obb` files and `.apk` so it can be published in other stores like Amazon? Can I just copy all the files in the asset folder to the apk main asset folder?

Comment: you can do something like 2 build configurations - one for google play, other for another store. Also you can just use your own server to store obb file, and download it not from google play, but from that server in any case - for google play store publishing, and for other stores

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to combine the `.obb` files and `.apk`?
>
> Can I just copy all the files in the asset folder to the apk main asset folder?

I don't think you could do this. `.obb` and `.apk` approximately have the same data in different structures for the different use cases. In addition, the apk will be signing and we can't change its content with a simple copy/zip file.

But I think you have at least 2 option to achieve your goal:

> Is there a way to combine the .obb files and .apk so it can be published in other stores like Amazon?

1. If you've configured your signing key you can build separate apk and bundle files and use them.

Or run to do this:

```
./gradlew bundleRelease assembleRelease
```

2. Build the `.obb` file and upload it to PlayConsole. Then in PlayConsole navigate to **App Bundle Explorer** menu. Selecting **Dowbloads** tab and at the bottom of the screen, you will see **Assets** section. Download universal apk. and use it for other markets.

[image]